# Unable to change max upload files size to more than 1024 Kb in Joomla (plupload script)

Tags: joomla, plupload

I faced with problem: unable to upload files more than 1024Kb. 
System said:

> File size error. The file exceeds the maximum allowed size of 1024 kb

[Error message img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D1oN.png)
I need to have opportunity to upload files 5Mb.
I've changed .htaccess file with the folowing rows with no success:

```
php_value post_max_size 5M
php_value upload_max_filesize 5M
```

I found *plupload.full.min.js* script
It seems to me this script responsible for upload file size limitation.
Please find ths script on my google drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Yg8ZpZjcwzesYWt8qoG7HoNkl3lc9LkZ

Tried to hide this block, but with no success again:

```
o.addFileFilter("max_file_size", function(e, t, n) {
3848         var r;
3849         e = o.parseSize(e), t.size !== r && e && t.size > e ? (this.trigger("Error", {
3850             code: o.FILE_SIZE_ERROR,
3851             message: o.translate("File size error."),
3852             file: t
3853         }), n(!1)) : n(!0)
3854     }),
```

Tried to change **k** variable also with on success:

```
    f = function(e) {
        if ("string" != typeof e) return e;
        var t = {
                t: 1099511627776,
                g: 1073741824,
                m: 1048576,
                k: 1024
            },
            n;
        return e = /^([0-9]+)([mgk]?)$/.exec(e.toLowerCase().replace(/[^0-9mkg]/g, "")), n = e[2], e = +e[1], t.hasOwnProperty(n) && (e *= t[n]), e
    };
```

Comment: Which version of joomla you are using and whether plupload belongs to any 3rd party component.

Comment: @AmitRay Joomla! 3.6.2 Stable and Joomla Platform 13.1.0 Stable
plupload script belongs to ZOO component. But in ZOO there is no such file upload limitation option.

Answer (score 0):

The script you're referencing to is just a JavaScript script. It is not responsible for handling any file size limitations. The server is responsible for that. To let the script know about the limitations, it renders the necessary configuration into the HTML output:

https://www.plupload.com/docs/v2/UI.Plupload

So we're back on the server side. Your server has a limitation for 1MB right now. You can use the Joomla System Information to figure out the correct value:

[image: Jooml System Information Screenshot]

Have a look for the values `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`. You already tried to modify them, but I guess this was not successful. I recommend contacting your hosting provider. Maybe they don't allow changes like that or you need to place them in a different folder.

Comment: Dear @SvenBluege i've already contacted with my hosting provider to change max filesize limitation, they changed `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` and it didn't help.

Comment: Please check the output of phpinfo or in the Joomla system Information.

Comment: i ran phpinfo and _upload_max_filesize_ is _5M_